# How to calculate the frequency in each column

Tags: r

I get the data from the questionnaire. So the data look like this:

```
ID    Q1_1  Q1_2  Q1_3  Q1_4  Q1_5  
par1    1     1     1     2     3    
par2    3     1     5     1     1    
par3    3     2     6     2     1    
par4    1     3     6     2     3    
par5    1     5     6     3     3    
par6    1     4     1     2     3    
par7    1     1     2     2     3
```

what I want to do is to calculate the frequency of each questions (parcipants need to choose from "1" to "6").
It might look like below. The first row (1-6) means the participant's answers.Q1_1, Q1_2,..., and Q1_5 are questions.
From the second row, the number means frequency.

```
        1  2  3  4  5  6 
Q1_1    5  0  2  0  0  0
Q1_2    3  1  1  1  1  0
Q1_3    2  1  0  0  1  3
Q1_4    1  5  1  0  0  0
Q1_5    2  0  5  0  0  0
```

I tried to use

```
a <- lapply(df, table)
b <- as.data.frame(a)
```

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 5, 4, 3, 6

I did get the frequency, but I cannot get the data frame.

Comment: It should be `as.data.frame`, is it because of this you are not getting the desired result, else this is just typing mistake.

Comment: @ashwinagrawal yes, it is a typing mistake. I revised it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stack()`

```
t(table(stack(df[-1])))

      values
ind    1 2 3 4 5 6
  Q1_1 5 0 2 0 0 0
  Q1_2 3 1 1 1 1 0
  Q1_3 2 1 0 0 1 3
  Q1_4 1 5 1 0 0 0
  Q1_5 2 0 5 0 0 0
```

Alternatively, picking up where you left off:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(df[-1], function(x) table(factor(x, levels = 1:6))))

     1 2 3 4 5 6
Q1_1 5 0 2 0 0 0
Q1_2 3 1 1 1 1 0
Q1_3 2 1 0 0 1 3
Q1_4 1 5 1 0 0 0
Q1_5 2 0 5 0 0 0
```

(Reproducible) data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("par1", "par2", "par3", "par4", "par5", "par6", "par7"), 
  Q1_1 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
  Q1_2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L), 
  Q1_3 = c(1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L), 
  Q1_4 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), 
  Q1_5 = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)
)
```